# Iframe in svg border responsive

Tags: html, css, svg, iframe

I'm trying to make like tablet with iframe. (Demo: http://tab.vn-rp.cz/). In some resolution it look fine, but when I drag window and start chaning resolutions, it get worse and iframe gets out of svg border around. I just have an ugly code below:

```
            /*iPhone4 iframe*/
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
              -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
              -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
               -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
                 -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
                  -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
                      user-select: none;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-height: 1000px) {
            #iphone4 {
                background-image: url("Tablet.svg");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height: 100%;
                width: 60%;
                margin: auto;
                position: relative;

            }

            #browser {
                height: 85.8%;
                width: 96%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 2.4%;
                border-radius: 3%;
                left: 2.1%;
                border: 0;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-height: 1000px) and (max-height: 1070px) {
            #iphone4 {
                background-image: url("Tablet.svg");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height: 100%;
                width: 65%;
                margin: auto;
                position: relative;

            }

            #browser {
                height: 75.2%;
                width: 96%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 2%;
                border-radius: 3%;
                left: 2.1%;
                border: 0;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-height: 1070px) {
            #iphone4 {
                background-image: url("Tablet.svg");
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height: 100%;
                width: 60%;
                margin: auto;
                position: relative;

            }

            #browser {
                height: 76.9%;
                width: 96%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 2.2%;
                border-radius: 3%;
                left: 2.1%;
                border: 0;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-height: 1000px) {
            .panilek {
                position: absolute;
                width: 97%;
                margin-top: 825px;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }

            .back {
                position: absolute;
                width: 1.5%;
                margin-top: 830px;
                margin-left: 300px;
            }

            .home {
                position: absolute;
                width: 1.6%;
                margin-top: 830px;
                margin-left: 550px;
            }

            .right {
                position: absolute;
                width: 1.9%;
                margin-top: 833px;
                margin-left: 800px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-height: 1000px) and (max-height: 1070px) {
            .panilek {
                position: absolute;
                width: 97%;
                margin-top: 782px;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }

            .back {
                position: absolute;
                width: 1.5%;
                margin-top: 790px;
                margin-left: 240px;
            }

            .home {
                position: absolute;
                width: 1.6%;
                margin-top: 790px;
                margin-left: 520px;
            }

            .right {
                position: absolute;
                width: 1.9%;
                margin-top: 790px;
                margin-left: 785px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-height: 1070px) {
            .panilek {
                position: absolute;
                width: 97%;
                margin-top: 825px;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }

            .back {
                position: absolute;
                width: 1.5%;
                margin-top: 830px;
                margin-left: 300px;
            }

            .home {
                position: absolute;
                width: 1.6%;
                margin-top: 830px;
                margin-left: 550px;
            }

            .right {
                position: absolute;
                width: 1.9%;
                margin-top: 833px;
                margin-left: 800px;
            }
        }
```

-- HTML Code

```
    <body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="iphone4" class="w3-animate-bottom">
        <iframe name="browser" id="browser" src="http://tab.vn-rp.cz/page.html"></iframe>
        <img class="panilek" src="http://tab.vn-rp.cz/panilek.svg" />
        <img onClick="back();" style="cursor:pointer;" class="back" src="http://tab.vn-rp.cz/leftbutton.svg" />
        <img onClick="$('#browser').attr('src', 'http://tab.vn-rp.cz/page.html');" style="cursor:pointer;" class="home" src="http://tab.vn-rp.cz/homebutton.svg" />
        <img onClick="$('#browser').attr('src', 'https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1');" style="cursor:pointer;" class="right" src="http://tab.vn-rp.cz/rightbutton.svg" />
    </div>
    <script>
        var canback = false;

        function back(){
            if(canback){
                window.history.back();
            }
        }

        window.onmessage = function(e){
            if(e.data == "home"){
                canback = false;
            }
            else if(e.data == "app"){
                canback = true;
            }
            else {
                alert("'" + e.data + "'");
            }
        };
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Is there some more efficient way to do it? If so, I will be so happy! Have a nice day all!

Comment: Is it possible to add HTML code?

Comment: HTML code added :)